# Robust Language Check Options for Linux Word Processing Software

Tags: software-recommendation

Dominantly, I use the pre-installed Liberation suite but in essence, I am looking for any word processing means that has robust spelling and grammar checking, and even language-based and style directions, like MS Word would do these:

- its very long - will suggest usage of it's instead of its
- sentence ends. But it was narrow. - if style check is on, it will suggest using However instead of but.
- and the common spelling and grammar errors as usual.

Any help will be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you are looking for is a grammar checker, there are a few options available:

. [**LanguageTool**](https://www.languagetool.org/) - available as an extension to LibreOffice. Follow [this guide](http://debianhelp.wordpress.com/2011/10/25/how-to-install-grammar-checker-in-libreoffice-in-ubuntu/) if you have difficulties installing.

. [**Queequeg**](http://queequeg.sourceforge.net/index-e.html) -  an English grammar checker for non-native English speakers. Support is lean but the Wiki page has many details; useful for LaTeX users.

. [**Abiword**](https://duckduckgo.com/l/?kh=-1&uddg=http%3A%2F%2Fabisource.com%2F) - has long included a grammar checking engine, which in its latest versions uses [Link Grammar theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_Grammar). Available from the Software Centre.

As an addendum, [**Readability Report**](http://extensions.services.openoffice.org/project/ReadabilityReport) may be an helpful tool to improve the readability of your text.

Beyond these suggestions there are a few more grammar/readability suites available under commercial licenses.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out any other software that do spell checking and auto correction while you are typing. The one Abiword is already mentioned in the above reply.

I would like to have few other suggestions such as using BEAN, Office Office or Ne office for such task. All of the above mentioned softwares are good and has the feature included in their latest versions. Also these are free to use softwares.

For more detailed reviews of above and few others please head over to http://www.wordprocessorfree.com where you can get many other software in full details and download links.

And yeah, Kingoffice is yet another one that i had used for few months and is a good software with rich feature including the one that you are interesting in...